# Don't show inactive users on the current top users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-accounts, reputation-leagues

There are users that have earned thousands of rep that are in the (yearly) reputation leagues, but they haven't logged on in a couple years. It's usually a case where the user has decided, for whatever reason to leave the network.
I feel it kinda ruins the top users pages, with a bunch of these inactive acocunts.

I think that the Weekly, Monthly and Yearly top users page should be reserved for **active** users.

---

### My proposal:

A automatic system to hide users from Yearly (Monthly and weekly) rankings if they haven't logged in (to any of their network accounts) for over a year.

- It would automatically reset when the user logs in (and possibly also does some sort of participation - vote, edit, comment etc.)

  - It would apply network-wide (as soon as they log into any one of their communities, it resets)
- They **would** still earn rep/badges etc.
- One could still search their profile and it will come up.

  - They just wouldn't be counted on the top users (for yearly, monthly and weekly) page.

---

**Examples:** (stats are for 2017)

> - https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/3936 #8 *(8,170 rep)* Last seen Jan 6 '15
> - https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/1286 #14 *(2,398 rep)* Last seen
>     Jul 13 '16
> - https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/41 #25 *(2,191 rep)* Last seen May 19 '15
> - https://superuser.com/users/1931 #13 *(7,964)* Last seen Jan 9 '12
> - https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998 #21 *(4,356 rep)*  Last seen Sep 18 '16

This one *almost* fits: (The one post from 2017 only gave 20 rep)

https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1375 #15 (2,377 rep)  Last seen Feb 3 '17

Comment: It *looks* from the title and the beginning of the post body that this request is totally different, to reinstate the culling of old, inactive accounts. That could be why you're getting downvotes. I think rephrasing it to make the request clear would reduce the downvotes a bit.

Comment: @Ano you're right, I've reworded and fixed it up (I hope)

Comment: Why do we even have these *user leagues*? If this features that doesn't add to the core of the SE network and now apparently is losing its value , just remove it, instead of going into a process to make those lists mean something different.

Comment: I think partially cause we've always had them, and they were a bit of overlord sanctioned fun...  also cheese.

Answer (score 10):

It's worth remembering that the reputation leagues are "just for a bit of fun", and they aren't *really* worth worrying about.

They aren't going to show up in anything but the all time high scores, and least for me, it's been motivating - I WILL CATCH UP WITH [JohnT](https://superuser.com/users/1931) some day.....

Maybe it's going to be a little like the old *Seinfeld* episode [The Frogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Frogger), and someone comes back years later, realizes his old high score hasn't been beaten, and <strike>gets a SE server hit by a truck</strike> decides to come back.

At the end of the day, it's just a bit of fun, and hiding our MVPs of the past kind of defeats the purpose of *All Time* top users.

As for annual, I suspect it would be hard. You can't coast on the HNQ effect for the most part, and you're somehow relying on passive rep to get there. Without specific examples, this feels like a solution looking for a problem.

Comment: I corrected it to be more specific to Yearly

Comment: eh, that kinda feels like moving the goalposts :(. My perfectly good reference won't work now

Comment: My edit came before your answer :P

Comment: I'm not sure how its possible to hit the yearly rep leagues entirely off passive rep (unless you're Jon Skeet).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Here on MSE, we had a user who hadn't logged in since 2009 hit the quarterly rep league after one of his answers received a massive amount of upvotes after being bumped.

Comment: ... https://stackexchange.com/leagues/174/year/graphicdesign/2017-01-01 2017 league. I donno man... you *probably* need to know how to find this to back up your question.

Comment: The link is broken. I suppose you mean https://superuser.com/users/1931.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've updated my post to include a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> There are users with literally thousands of rep that are in the reputation leagues, but they haven't logged on in a couple years.
>
> I think that the top users page should be reserved for active users; at least for the Yearly, monthly, weekly ones

That is kind-of contradicting. Users can earn reputation while inactive, but usually that isn't enough to be in the top ranking of a site for a short period (week, month, etc). That means that inactive users should be filtered out already by not earning too much reputation in that period. Only the users with a high reputation in that period will be shown on the top spots.

And even then: that user, active or not, did earn that reputation. Why should that user not be listed because of inactivity?

Comment: I don't understand how it's a contradiction.

Comment: The top user of the year... should be an active user, no?

Comment: How would they are thousands of reputation while inactive?

Comment: Because they have many (popular) posts from previous years

Comment: Saying that this won't happen, when the OP is *providing concrete examples of it actually happening* is pretty pointless.

Comment: The question added *even more* examples with more in depth citations 6 minutes ago.  It still had examples from the original revision.

Comment: +1 as even if inactive, the fact those users get upvote mean they attract new users and mean their content is still valuable to the site content. So hidding a inactive user, that still get upvote seem unfair to me, as they indirectly still help SE to grow

Answer (score 0):

Let me think of an analogy. Who in your opinion is the best F1 pilot of all time? But do not vote for Ayrton Senna because he is not driving anymore.

If an answer is good, and it is upvoted for a "new generation of users" that is great. And it should simply count.

Besides that, stop worrying about that. If the user is not login in anymore I just hope they are Ok.

Comment: I didn't say they shouldn't get the votes or even the rep, just that they shouldn't be on the League of the *active* top users.